# How can I view my progress on bonus levels

Tags: angry-birds-space

In Angry Birds Space there are some bonus levels that appear when you hit special rocks.  The birds get sucked into a mini black hole or something, you do the bonus level, and then they pop back out and you complete the original level.  I guess this is to replace the golden egg levels, but I don't see a screen where I can see the ones I've unlocked or finished.  Is there an in-game way to view the progress on these extra levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These levels are under Eggsteroids. From the screen containing all the planets, if you scroll over to the 4th planet, you'll see the Eggsteroids levels. Clicking on the planet will show you any unlocked levels and allow you to replay that level. These appear to be comparable to the Golden Egg levels of the earlier games.

[image]

Comment: I assumed that was another world, guess not!  Thanks, I'll vote you up when I get 15 reputation.